# element wise multiplication vector with rows of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a vector [0 1 2] and a matrix of size 3 x n. How can I multiply each element of the vector with the corresoponding row of the matrix. Each element of row 0 should be multiplied with 0, each element of row 1 should be multiplied with 1 and so on?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Let v be the vector and A the matrix, I tried:  v = v[:,None]  * A

Comment: `v[:, None] * A` seems to do what you ask for. What was wrong with that?

Comment: v is casted to a 3x3 matrix where the vectors are stored as columns. How is this then multiplied?

Comment: It's multiplied the way your question describes. Just create some small sample data and run it yourself to see how it works, e.g.: `v = np.array([0, 1, 2]); A = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]); A * v[:, None]`

Comment: I see. The vector is 3 times replicated as 3x3 matrix and then each column of it multiplied elementwise by the column of A, since we have elementwise multiplication *

Comment: The general term for this is "broadcasting" ([dimensions with size 1 are stretched or "copied" to match the other](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)).

Comment: Is my explanation therefore right?

Comment: @Sarah Yes, that sounds right: `v[:, None].shape` is `(3, 1)` which gets stretched to `(3, 3)` to match `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using numpy. You can use `matrix *= vector.reshape(-1, 1)`. This will convert the vector to a column, then multiply the rows.

Comment: Then I would multply the second element in row 0 with 1 and not 0?

Comment: That's not what happened when I ran it.